# Auto-Format a newly created file using VS Code Extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a VS Code Extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danish-naglekar.dataverse-devtools). In this extension, I am creating a linker file that helps me link the local file to the files on the server. When the file gets created it is always created with all content in a single line. How can I ensure that a default formatted is invoked and the contents of the file are not saved all in one line?

Comment: open the file in an editor and call the format document command

Comment: That is one way to do it but I wanted the extension to create the file with the formatting itself so users do not have to format it. Because the file also gets updated from the extension and when that happens the formatting is lost.

Comment: you can program to open the file, format, save, close the file

Comment: That is what I am looking for, but couldn't find the formatting & close method in the extension API

Comment: find that command in the keybinding GUI